# SQL unknown 10 desc script

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am struggling with the below SQL script relating to the bolded "10 desc" at the end of the script
This field is not in the original tables.  It was created separately.

I don't exactly know what it is for but if I remove it it will give me different result.  Hope I could have some guidance on this.

```
SELECT ce.[Agreement ID], m.AGREEMENT_NAME, ce.Max_Deduct_Bond, d.[Product Type], d.Margin, d.Ccy, Left(Right(d.[Margin],12),2) AS Cty, d.Posted_Received_Flag, d.[Market Value], (d.[Market Value]*r.[Rate]) AS [Market Value HKD]
FROM [Step 0103 - CE: CE Source] AS ce,
[201_0002 - Get_Agreement_Treats_Mapping] AS m, 
[201_0000 - Get_nCOMS_201_Details] AS d, 
SysReportDate AS sd,
 SysTOR AS r
WHERE (((ce.[Agreement ID])=[m].[AGREEMENT_ID] And (ce.[Agreement ID])="11") AND ((m.AGREEMENT_NAME)=[d].[Agreement]) AND ((ce.Max_Deduct_Bond)<>0) AND ((d.[Product Type])='Bond') AND ((d.[Reporting Date])=[sd].[Reporting Date]) AND ((sd.Date_Code)='01_CM') AND ((r.[Ccy Code])=[d].[Ccy]))
ORDER BY ce.[Agreement ID], 10 DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

10 in order by mean its ordering by 10th column listed in the select statement, which in your query is `[Market Value HKD]`.

which is not recommended to do so , and your order by statement changes depend on the order of columns returned in the select .
always use column names:

```
... ORDER BY ce.[Agreement ID], [Market Value HKD] DESC;
```